# ERROR in The target entry-point "@angular-material-extensions/faq" has missing dependencies:

Tags: angular, angular-material

[image]

https://angular-material-extensions.github.io/faq/doc/index.html
i try to add import { MatFaqModule } from '@angular-material-extensions/faq'; this module on angular.js like it told me .please help me

Comment: your question is not clear

Answer (score 10):

install all dependency
`npm i @angular/cdk @angular/material @angular/flex-layout @angular/animations @angular/forms`

and

change angular material import of file
`node_modules\@angular-material-extensions\faq\esm2015\faq.js`
to also

```
import { MatCardModule } from '@angular/material/card';
import { MatToolbarModule } from '@angular/material/toolbar';
import { MatButtonModule } from '@angular/material/button';
import { MatInputModule } from '@angular/material/input';
import { MatIconModule } from '@angular/material/icon';
import { MatExpansionModule } from '@angular/material/expansion';
```